# Regex get everything between two words inside {}

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to parse a rpt file and extract everything in between {} after the pattern [SAMPLE] until this pattern occurs the next time. So it wold be [SAMPLE] {This is the data I want} [SAMPLE]. There is also the possibility that only one [SAMPLE] is included in a file, so there can be a single or multiple [SAMPLE] section(s).

The file looks something like this:

```
[SAMPLE]
{
[MS]
{
lots of text...
;Mass   % BPI
238.85  0.943
247.64  0.984
378.65  0.990
...
}
[CHROMATOGRAM]
{
lots of text...
}
lots of text...
[MS]
{
;Mass   % BPI
238.85  0.943
247.64  0.984
378.65  0.990
...
}
lots of text...
{
;Mass   % BPI
238.85  0.943
247.64  0.984
378.65  0.990
...
}
}
[SAMPLE]
{
[MS]
{
lots of text
;Mass   % BPI
238.85  0.943
247.64  0.984
378.65  0.990
...
}
[CHROMATOGRAM]
{
lots of text...
}
lots of text...
[MS]
{
;Mass   % BPI
238.85  0.943
247.64  0.984
378.65  0.990
...
}
lots of text...
{
;Mass   % BPI
238.85  0.943
247.64  0.984
378.65  0.990
...
}
}
```

I tried to use this pattern:

```
\[SAMPLE\]\s*{([^{}]+)}
```

but that only gives the first section in between {}

There are many {} that open and close in between the [SAMPLE] sections. Does any one know what regex I can use to get the data?

Comment: Did you use `re.find` or `re.findall` ?

Comment: You can leverage the context: if the section goes up to `[UPPERCASE]` + `NEWLINE` + `{`, you may just use `re.findall(r'^\[SAMPLE\]\r?\n\{(.*?)\r?\n}\r?\n\[[A-Z]+]\n', text, re.M  | re.S)`

Comment: With Python PyPi regex, you may use `for m in regex.finditer(r'^\[SAMPLE]\r?\n({(?P<result>(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*)})', text, regex.M | regex.S):
    print(m.group("result"))`, see [demo](https://rextester.com/BVGMK49092)

Comment: @Tserenjamts re.findall()

Comment: @bimarian So, you should consider using `regex.finditer` if you want to use a regex for this.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I imported regex but it doesn't find anything I saw that this was for Python 2.7.x does this also work for Python 3.7? Also it seems like this pattern only gives me the first {} section inside [SAMPLE] I would need to get everything inside [SAMPLE] until the next [SAMPLE] section starts and then until the very end of the document, if there is no more [SAMPLE] section. I tried out some things but none of them has worked for me.

Comment: Do you mean you need just `re.findall(r'\[SAMPLE][^[]*(?:\[(?!SAMPLE])[^[]*)*', text)`? https://ideone.com/S8tWS1?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew so the '------' mark the end of the findings and below the new ones right so I could append the (in this example) two lists to one and later call them by index (already have the code for that).

Comment: Come on, that is just a demo, I printed the matches for better visual effect :) You would use `list_of_results = re.findall(r'\[SAMPLE][^[]*(?:\[(?!SAMPLE])[^[]*)*', text)`, see https://ideone.com/D07NSg. So, is it what you need?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I know I was just wondering if they meant to symbol that which they do thank you so much for your effort, really appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
list_of_results = re.findall(r'\[SAMPLE][^[]*(?:\[(?!SAMPLE])[^[]*)*', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Je4uWU/1) and the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/D07NSg).

The regex basically matches any substring starting with `[SAMPLE]` and up to the closest occurrence of `[SAMPLE]` or end of string.

**Details**

- `\[SAMPLE]` - a `[SAMPLE]` substring
- `[^[]*` - 0 or more chars other than `[`
- `(?:\[(?!SAMPLE])[^[]*)*`  -  zero or more sequences of

  - `\[(?!SAMPLE])` - a `[` char not immediately followed with `SAMPLE]`
  - `[^[]*` - 0 or more chars other than `[`